# Why can't i use these Selected Indexes in a method? - HRK to EURO Currency Converter

Tags: c#, winforms

Pretty new to C#.

I want to read the user input from a combo box and use the selected currencies in a method which converts one to another. The output isn't in console, it's on a Windows form.

This is my combo box input read code:

```
public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double first = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}

public void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double second = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
}
```

And this is my code that uses the selected indexes and converts them:

```
internal class Currencies
{
    public double[] Convert(double[] currencies, int amount)
    {
        double[] convertedAmount = new double[currencies.Length];

        if (Converter.comboBox1.first == HRK && Converter.comboBox2.second == EURO)
        {
            int exchangeRate1 = 1;
            double exchangeRate2 = 7.4;

            for (int i = 0; i < currencies.Length; i++)
            {
                convertedAmount[i] = amount * exchangeRate1 / exchangeRate2;
            }
        }
        else if (Converter.comboBox1.first == EURO && Converter.comboBox2.seocnd == HRK)
        {
            int exchangeRate1 = 1;
            double exchangeRate2 = 7.4;

            for (int i = 0; i < currencies.Length; i++)
            {
                convertedAmount[i] = amount * exchangeRate1 / exchangeRate2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        return convertedAmount;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the method let me use the variables "first" and "second" where I stored the selected indexes to convert the currencies?

Comment: You don't ned those variables anyway. Just get the `SelectedIndex` of each `ComboBox` when and where you need to actually perform the conversion.

Comment: I just had a closer look at your code. Regardless of anything else, I'm not sure why you would think that `Converter.comboBox1.first` should work at all, regardless of scope. You have declared that variable in a form - in a method in a form, but in a form - so why do you think you should be able to access it via that `ComboBox`? It isn't part of the control.

Comment: @EduardoGomez, this is WinForms, not WPF.

Comment: Where does that `Convert` method get called? Is it from the form containing the `ComboBoxes`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, it's called from that form.

Comment: In that case, the form should be getting the currency selections from the `ComboBoxes` itself at that point, then passing them into that method as arguments. The method should not be retrieving data from the form that just called it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry when problem I have

```
 public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

you must To Add new class such a `utils` and you must to `{ get ; set }`

every you  have
Concept
This is better

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the selectedIndexChanged procedures since you are declaring local variables there that get garbage collected after the procedure fires.

Just replace *first* and *second* in your Convert() method with *comboBox1.SelectedValue* and *comboBox2.SelectedValue*

Answer (score -2):

You can use this approach, this is what I always do in my apps

1. Create three folders (ViewModel, View, and model)
2. Install fody.propertyChange from Nugget
3. Create a viewModel for your page
4. Define a variable `string SelectedIted {get; set;}` in your viewwModel
5. in the xaml code-behind for your page, put `DataContext = new NameOfYourViewModel`

Something like this

---

```
 <ComboBox
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="10,0,10,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            ui:ControlHelper.PlaceholderText="Select Lenguague"
            DisplayMemberPath="Value.Name"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LanguagesDictionary}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            SelectedValuePath="Value.Code" />
```

---

in Your VM

```
       public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

---

in your XAML code behind

```
            DataContext = new AudioPageViewModel();
```

Comment: The question states that it's WinForms.

Comment: even windows form has some kind of DataContext

Comment: Trying to help is admirable but answers still need to actually answer the actual question that was asked, which this one doesn't. Do you really think someone who doesn't even understand variable scope is going to be able to translate a WPF solution to WinForms? Even if they can, they should have to.